# Authentication in ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I am using VS2005 C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am currently using user authentication of the option : **From the internet**, therefore I have a list of created users and roles.

However, I would like to change my authentication to using *ActiveDirectory*, therefore I presume I would need to use the authentication option : **From a local network**.

But after I selected to authenticate from the local network, I am unable to add or manage users anymore.

May I know what are the steps that is required for me to change from my current authentication type to the use of Windows *ActiveDirectory*?

Any guides are greatly appreciated

Comment: Why not let IIS do the heavy lifting for you? Change your Website/Application authentication to `Windows Authentication`.

Comment: @M.Babcock May I know where do I change my Website/Application authentication? Thanks

Comment: Which version of IIS are you running?

Comment: @M.Babcock I tried searching for the IIS ver. in my pc but I can't seem to locate it somehow. It is possible that I may not have IIS installed in my pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add or manage users when you move to Active Directory.  They have to be managed from the Active Directory Users and Computers MMC snap-in in the Domain Controller.  Your web server talks to AD for authentication, it doesn't manage AD.

(that's not strictly true, you can write code to manage users, but it's going to be quite a bit of work, and it's just easier to do it from AD).

Comment: My objective is to retrieve all users in the AD and list them in my webpage foe user management for my web application. However I am having some trouble logging in using Windows Authentication atm